# Tracking Changes in Retail Store Ownership Over Time

Tags: sql, oracle

[Sample Data Set and Desired Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0Kaw.png)

I have a list of retail stores that have changed ownership over time (from company owned, to licensed or franchised and back to company owned). I'm trying to track the count of stores open each month under each ownership type. For each change in ownership I have a new line item in the data set, each of which has a corresponding Start and End date for the change.

I'm trying to count the stores by ownership type for each month of the data and I'm having trouble figuring out how to count the stores for the all the months IN BETWEEN the dates of the ownership start and end dates. Hopefully the picture makes it perfectly clear what I'm looking to do.

```
select
    b.fscl_yr_num
    ,b.fscl_per_in_yr_num
    ,a.ownr_type_cd
    ,sum(case when a.line_start_dt < b.end_dt and a.line_end_dt <= b.End_Dt then 1 else 0 end)
from
(
    (
    select *
    from
        (select
            store_num
            ,ownr_type_cd
            ,case when store_term_dt is not null then 'Closed' else 'Open' end as Status
            ,case when to_date(trim(store_open_dt),'DD-MON-YY') > to_date(trim(eff_from_dt),'DD-MON-YY') then to_date(trim(store_open_dt),'DD-MON-YY') else to_date(trim(eff_from_dt),'DD-MON-YY') end as Line_Start_Dt
            ,case when store_term_dt is null then eff_to_dt 
                when to_date(trim(store_term_dt),'DD-MON-YY') < to_date(trim(eff_to_dt),'DD-MON-YY') then to_date(trim(store_term_dt),'DD-MON-YY') else to_date(trim(eff_to_dt),'DD-MON-YY') end as Line_End_Dt
        from
            (select
                store_num
                ,store_open_dt
                ,store_term_dt
                ,eff_from_dt
                ,eff_to_dt
                ,ownr_type_cd
            from
                appca.d_store_vers
            where
                upper(cntry_cd_2_dgt_iso) = 'GB'
                and postal_cd not like ('BT%')
                and store_open_dt is not null
            group by
                store_num
                ,store_open_dt
                ,store_term_dt
                ,eff_from_dt
                ,eff_to_dt
                ,ownr_type_cd
            order by
              store_num
              ,eff_from_dt)
        group by
            store_num
            ,ownr_type_cd
            ,case when store_term_dt is not null then 'Closed' else 'Open' end
            ,case when to_date(trim(store_open_dt),'DD-MON-YY') > to_date(trim(eff_from_dt),'DD-MON-YY') then to_date(trim(store_open_dt),'DD-MON-YY') else to_date(trim(eff_from_dt),'DD-MON-YY') end
            ,case when store_term_dt is null then eff_to_dt 
                when to_date(trim(store_term_dt),'DD-MON-YY') < to_date(trim(eff_to_dt),'DD-MON-YY') then to_date(trim(store_term_dt),'DD-MON-YY') else to_date(trim(eff_to_dt),'DD-MON-YY') end
        order by
            1 asc
            ,2 asc
            ,3 asc)
    where
        to_date(trim(line_start_dt),'DD-MON-YY') < to_date(trim(line_end_dt),'DD-MON-YY')
    ) A
right join

    --Calendar Table--
    (
    select 
        fscl_yr_num, fscl_per_in_yr_num, Cal_dt min(to_date(trim(cal_dt),'DD-MON-YY')) as Start_Dt, max(to_date(trim(cal_dt),'DD-MON-YY')) as End_Dt
    from
        appca.d_cal
    where
        fscl_yr_num is between 1990 and 2018
    group by
        fscl_yr_num, fscl_per_in_yr_num 
    order by 
        1 asc, 2 asc
    ) B
on A.line_end_dt = B.cal_dt
)
group by
    b.fscl_yr_num
    ,b.fscl_per_in_yr_num
    ,a.ownr_type_cd
order by
    b.fscl_yr_num
    ,b.fscl_per_in_yr_num
;
```

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures.  Also show what you have tried.

Comment: Alright, I figured a picture was the easiest/cleanest method to show results.

Comment: I amended the post to show my code I've tried. But I really only need help in assigning 1's to month in between dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this case:

```
sum(case when createTime >(cast(year(createTime) as varchar) +'-'+cast( MONTH(createTime) as varchar)+'-1') and createTime <(cast(year(createTime) as varchar) +'-'+cast( MONTH(createTime) as varchar)+'-31')
then 1 else 0 end) 'Company'
```